# Spfx Web Part - API call sometimes fails to execute

Tags: web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts, webapi

I have a custom web part that uses `aadHttpClientFactory` to authenticate with AAD and then get data from an API secured with AAD.

It works flawlessly most of the time. Periodically, though, it gets the `AadHttpClient` and then goes to run the `get()` command to retrieve data from the API but a response never comes back.

It seems to happen most often when the API has been idle for a while - like when I run it for the first time in the morning.

My first thought was that it's an issue with the API not coming back from idle well but if I hit the API from a browser, it works without issue. It seems to only happen from the custom web part which makes me think the `get()` isn't firing at all.

Here's my code:

```
console.log("Getting client...");
this.context.aadHttpClientFactory
  .getClient('<API Client ID>')
  .then((client: AadHttpClient): void => {
    console.log("Got client. Calling API...");

    client
      .get('https://www.mydomain.com/myAPI', AadHttpClient.configurations.v1)
      .then((response: HttpClientResponse): Promise<any> => {
        console.log("Got response from API: (" + response.status + ") " + response.statusText);

        if(response.status == 200){
          return response.json();
        }
        else {
          throw "(" + response.status + ") " + response.statusText;
        }

      })
      .then((data: any): void => {
        // process the data
        console.log(data);
      }, (err: any): void => {
        console.log("Error getting API data..." + err);
        this.context.statusRenderer.renderError(this.domElement, "Unable to retrieve data. " + err);
      });
  }, (err: any): void => {
    console.log("Error getting client...");
    this.context.statusRenderer.renderError(this.domElement, err);
  });
```

As you can see, I have several `console.log()` statements telling me where I'm at in the code and when I have the problem, I get this in the console:

```
Getting client...
Got client. Calling API...
```

And then nothing after that. If the `get()` command was firing, wouldn't it timeout eventually or return an error code?

If I refresh the page several times, it'll eventually start working again.

Why is my web part hanging?

EDIT: I noticed that I'm getting this error in the console when it fails:

> Blocked script execution in '`<URL>`' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.

Comment: Here's a thought: Is it possible that an old access token is getting cached on the SharePoint site and I'm only spotting the problem after leaving my browser open long enough for the token to expire? Or should calling `getClient()` reset all the token info regardless of how long the window has been open?

Comment: Do you happen to have resolved this issue? I get the same problem. Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: I created a bug report with Microsoft which they confirmed was a problem on their side with how custom web parts share access tokens with out of the box web parts. Still waiting on confirmation that it’s fixed.

Comment: If you have any out of the box web parts on the same page, remove them or move them to different pages. If your custom web part starts working, you have the same problem I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a bug report with Microsoft shortly after creating this question and quickly found that several other people were having the same issue. Microsoft confirmed this to be a bug with how web parts share access tokens.

My ticket got combined with another slightly different but similar issue related to the same token sharing functionality and while I think they've addressed my specific issue, as of this answer's creation (March 30, 2021), Microsoft isn't willing to confirm that they've fixed anything and the second issue that was combined with mine definitely hasn't been addressed. Your mileage may vary.

You can track the ticket's progress over on [GitHub](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/4892#).